# Переменная tkinter не изменяется при изменении состояния CheckBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, checkbox

Проблема заключается в следующем: когда я ставлю флажок напротив, допустим, Volume и нажимаю кнопку Submit, в выводе я получаю ноль, а хотелось бы единичку. Возможно скажете, что мне надо работать с классами, но...может можно как-то обойтись без них?)

```
from tkinter import *

def bInput(event):

    def retrieve_input():
        Radius=rText.get("1.0",END)
        print(Radius)
        Height=hText.get("1.0",END)
        print(Height)
        Density=dText.get("1.0",END)
        print(Density)
        print(var1.get(), var2.get())

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Circle")
    root.geometry("300x250")

    WarningM = Label(root, text='Please, enter NUMBERS, not letters and symbols!').pack()

    RadiusL = Label(root, text='Radius:').pack()
    rText = Text(root, height=1, width=10)
    rText.pack()

    HeightL = Label(root, text='Height:').pack()
    hText = Text(root, height=1, width=10)
    hText.pack()

    DensityL = Label(root, text='Density:').pack()
    dText = Text(root, height=1, width=10)
    dText.pack()

    var1 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text='Volume', variable=var1).pack()

    var2 = IntVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text='Mass', variable=var2).pack()

    Button(root, text='Submit', command=lambda: retrieve_input()).pack()


def bWork(event):
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Results")
    root.geometry("200x200")


def bExit(event):
    exit()


root = Tk()
root.title("%yna kakaya-ta") 
root.geometry("300x150") 

b_input = Button(root, text="Input", width = 10, height=2)
b_input.bind("<Button-1>", bInput)
b_input.pack()

b_work = Button(root, text="Work", width = 10, height=2)
b_work.bind("<Button-1>", bWork) 
b_work.pack() 

b_exit = Button(root, text="Exit", width = 10, height=2)
b_exit.bind("<Button-1>", bExit) 
b_exit.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не изменяется поле IntVar() в классе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/929706/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-intvar-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос с аналогичной проблемой: [**Не изменяется поле IntVar() в классе**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/929706/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-intvar-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5/929727)

Проблема в том, что вы дочерние окна создаете через `Tk()`, а нужно через `Toplevel()`.

Просто поменял в `bInput` `Tk` на `Toplevel`:

[image: Скриншот]